How can I get my native REPL to pickup my local source code: vscode native repl
I am trying to enable the new native REPL tool in vscode to see/pickup my local source code, but can't seem to figure out the configuration steps...

Have you checked out the documentation? What version of VS Code are you using? At a minimum, you may need to add "python.REPL.sendToNativeREPL": true to your settings.json file.

Yes I have, but nothing is mentioned specifically about configuring the native repl to be able to pickup the PYTHONPATH env variable and such.
So far, I have created a .env file with the PYTHONPATH listed in it but for some reason that isn't working.
Edit: yes I enabled the setting you mentioned as well.

Native REPL use built-in python interpreter. Or you can use Terminal REPL to enable external environmental variables.
